# line profiler vs pytest --durations

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, line-profiler

I have two programs in python which do the same thing, in line profiler one program for certain test is faster than another but in pytest --durations(for this certain test) is viceversa. Can somebody explain that behaviour.I need know execution time for certain test.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could be useful to run line-profiler inside your tests to compare. I wrote [a plugin](https://github.com/mgaitan/pytest-line-profiler) that may help. Feedback is very welcome.